# Keep labels on top

Tags: vb.net

I run the following block of code as the last thing in my Form.load:

```
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf c IsNot NameLabels Then
        c.SendToBack()
    End If
Next
```

'NameLabels' is a class that inherits the regular old label control.  Difference is that I have a special event handler for the NameLabels that allows me to move them around with the mouse.

I've tried switching it a bit with the following:

```
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf c Is NameLabels Then
        c.BringToFront()
    End If
Next
```

What I'm looking to do here is to ensure that any NameLabels always remain on top of all other controls.  Because they move, sometimes when the form is re-drawn, other controls stack on top of my NameLabels.  Which makes it difficult to see them or access them.

Since I'm posting here, you can safely assume that the block of code is not doing what I expect of it.  Is there a way to 100% ensure that all controls of type NameLabels will remain on top of all other controls in my form?  (Note: I've already got code in place that ensures no two NameLabels can have the same location.  They can partially overlap as needs be, but they will never have the same (x,y) coordinates. (Note#2: All NameLabels are also all the same size, just fyi.))

Comment: Are the labels in a panel or other container control?  The BringToFront Code should work otherwise.

Comment: Nope.  Just on the main form, no other containers.  And I agree, it should work.  Since it doesn't, I'm thinking that during the painting of the form, it's not finished putting other controls on the form before that block of code is run.

Comment: You would have to post all of the code that duplicates the problem.

Comment: That's a lot of code and I think that might be going above and beyond for this board.  I'll keep hammering at it.  My code has lots of little "This should work, why doesn't it?" issues. Too much of a rookie to know why yet.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: Instead of inheriting from Label, you could write extension methods `BringToFront` and `SendToBack` for Label.

Comment: Only the code that duplicates the problem.  Create a new project and recreate the issue with minimal code.

Comment: I've just written a bit of quick and dirty code with  a class NameLabels that only inherits the label Class and everything works just fine, So it looks like it is probably some other code that interferes with it. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks all.  Did a bit of testing overnight and it looks like there's an issue deep in my code causing this.  A test application does work fine.  I'll have to narrow down the problem area and re-ask the question if I need to.